# Unable to find fragment when view is generated in service

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement a floating map view that is on top of all apps.

The layout of the floating View.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bubble"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_overlay_wrapper"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bubble"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The idea is to change animate the visibility of the child RelativeLayout and have a map View in there.

This layout is inflated from a service and added to the window manager.

I get the following error when inflating.

```
07-29 00:36:10.121 11682-11682/com.derp.derp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.derp.derp, PID: 11682
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.derp.derp.BubbleService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3157)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1535)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.derp.derp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.derp.derp-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                      at com.derp.derp.BubbleService.onCreate(BubbleService.java:65)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3147)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1535)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Note: This error does not happen when I copy and paste the fragment into the activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try to change SupportMapFragment ==> MapFragment

```
         <fragment
            android:id="@+id/homeMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```